# Inserting into a specific Excel worksheet from an SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sql-server-2008

Like the title says.  I have researched this thoroughly, and I cannot find a satisfactory method for inserting SQL data returned from a stored procedure into a specific tab (worksheet) on an Excel workbook.

I tried using the OPENROWSET() method in the stored procedure, but it says I have to link to another server to use it.  I would prefer to do it through C# code anyway.

I tried various methods using CopyFromRecordSet, OLEDB record sets, etc.- the only method I found for inserting using OLEDB was to insert specific values, not a recordset.

I would prefer to insert the entire recordset at once instead of using loops, because we are talking about 200,000+ records.
Can someone give me some example code to do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: There are lots of examples on how to do this using C# along with other 3rd party dll's or using ITextSharp, or writing your own code.. here is a google query that has many results that you can read up on using a DataTable for example [Inserting into Excel from a Datatable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+stackoverflow+inserting+data+from+datatable+into+Excel+spread+sheet)

Comment: Excel has built-in support for several data sources. Have you researched those options as well?

Comment: Have you tried Power Query on Excel?

Comment: @dfundako:  MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: @MethodMan:  I will research your suggestion, but it seems to be pointing me to the same results I was getting before.

Comment: @Vercelli :  The problem is, the server where the code is, is secured- we can't add anything to it other than what the government approves.

Comment: you can actually add things like this to your code in regards to using C# and getting data into a Datatable.. then writing your own code to insert into excel even if you have to save the file as .csv there are plenty of ways to skin this cat.. do they allow you to use `SSIS` ?

Comment: @MethodMan:  Thanks for the links!  I found some code that casts the DataTable to save as a .CSV file, then I found more code (in another search) that will open the .CSV file and add it as a worksheet to the existing Excel file.  It is very fast.  Then all I had to do was format manually and it works.  I will  post code when I return to work on Monday.